# Is it possible to do a 'find . -ctime n' in JDK7?

Tags: java, java-7, file-attributes, filetime

Is it possible to do a equivalent 'find . -ctime n' (Unix command) in JDK7? i.e. find all files based on last changed time?
I had a look at the new FileVisitor/BasicFileAttributes/SimpleFileVisitor classes but I cannot see how it could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me (using Files.walkFileTree and a FileVisitor) :

FileTime ctime = (FileTime) Files.getAttribute(path, "unix:ctime");

Answer (score 2):

In the JDK 7 Forums there is [discussion opened](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se-snapshots-project-feedback/jdk7-why-no-lastchangetime-method-basicfileattributes) on the subject

It basically says:

> From creationTime's description "If
>   the file system implementation does
>   not support a time stamp to indicate
>   the time when the file was created
>   then this method returns an
>   implementation specific default value,
>   typically the last-modified-time or a
>   FileTime representing the epoch
>   (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)". So the
>   behavior you observe is expected. The
>   time of last status change is
>   available if you really need it, try
>   Files.getAttribute(path,
>   "unix:ctime").

So, your own answer seems to be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the creation time of a file by calling `getCreationTime()` on its file attributes object.  You can do a directory tree walk using `Files.walkFileTree` and a `FileVisitor`.  Put these together and you can implement `find . -ctime n`.

Comment: Creation time and last changed time are not the same.
I've already tried getCreationTime(), lastAccessTime(), and lastModifiedTime(). None of them mimic -ctime.

Comment: As another example, if I were to sort by getCreationTime(), then this would be the equivalent of 'ls -lt', but what I'm trying to do is a 'ls -ltc' sort.

Comment: After further investigation, I think getCreationTime() is broken.
It seems that getCreationTime() and lastModifiedTime() are returning the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what creationTime's javadoc says:

If the file system implementation does not support a time stamp to indicate the time when the file was created then this method returns an implementation specific default value, typically the last-modified-time or a FileTime representing the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

As the creation is not typical on Unix/Linux then the method is returning the last modified time.